# What is the significance of wearing the namam on the forehead?

Tags: tilak

What is the significance of wearing the "namam" on the forehead? What do the red and white components indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red/yellow line in the middle - represents Lakshmi, White component  represents the feet Vishnu. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srivaishnava_Urdhva_Pundra